# parsing html tags inside the xml sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

I have this XML data.

```
     set @PROGRAM_XML ='<PROGRAM>
      <ORG_GUID>FA9DC609-B8C0-4943-84E0-9D7BC0BC1027</ORG_GUID>
     <LONG_DESCRIPTION><p>
     <u><em>hi</em></u></p></LONG_DESCRIPTION>
     <SHORT_DESCRIPTION><p>
     <strong>hi</strong></p></SHORT_DESCRIPTION> 
     </PROGRAM>'
```

I am using

```
      EXEC SP_XML_PREPAREDOCUMENT @XMLHANDLER OUTPUT, @PROGRAM_XML

     SELECT
        ORG_GUID 
        ,LONG_DESCRIPTION
        ,SHORT_DESCRIPTION
    FROM
        OPENXML(@XMLHANDLER,'/PROGRAM',2)
     WITH
    (
        ORG_GUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
        ,LONG_DESCRIPTION  VARCHAR(2000)
        ,SHORT_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(2000)
    )
```

when selecting i am getting the data as.

```
    ORG_GUID                                                           LONG_DESCRIPTION              SHORT_DESCRIPTION                       
      FA9DC609-B8C0-4943-84E0-9D7BC0BC1027                       hi                                                 hi
```

But  I want to get it as

```
      <ORG_GUID>                                                            LONG_DESCRIPTION                               SHORT_DESCRIPTION                       
       FA9DC609-B8C0-4943-84E0-9D7BC0BC1027         <p><u><em>hi</em></u></p>      <p><strong>hi</strong></p>
```

why its ignoring the inner HTML tags. Can anyone give me a catch.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL Server version is 2005 and higher, you can use such code:

```
 SELECT 
    b.value('ORG_GUID[1]','UNIQUEIDENTIFIER') AS ORG_GUID,
    CAST(b.query('LONG_DESCRIPTION/*') AS NVARCHAR(2000)) AS LONG_DESCRIPTION,
    CAST(b.query('SHORT_DESCRIPTION/*') AS NVARCHAR(2000)) AS SHORT_DESCRIPTION
    FROM @PROGRAM_XML.nodes('//PROGRAM') a(b)
```